# What is the daily transaction limit for Bitinstant?

Tags: transactions, bitinstant

I know that bitinstant limits individual trades to 3 digits or $999 per transaction, but they make no mention in their [FAQ](https://www.bitinstant.com/faq) about the size of the daily limit they impose.

I was wondering if anyone knew the exact number?

**Note:** I think this number may vary depending on where your sending money from, however I'm specifically interested in the limit regarding sending money from mtgox to bitstamp and vice versa.

**Update:** I emailed them and they confirmed that the limit is in fact $2000 per day.

**Update:** Since this question bitinstant has updated their service. You can now be verified by sending in a photo idea and have your limit upped to $10,000 per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2000 per day. Right above their captcha-like thing, it says the limits in small text.

Answer (score 0):

From [the front page](https://bitinstant.com/) of bitinstant.com:

> limits 500$ for all transfers, 1000$ for cash bank deposits, 2000$ per
>   per day, minimal order 20$